# setting the default string value of Python's collections.defaultdict

Tags: python, collections

I am using Python 3.2.3 and want to change the default returned string value:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(str)
d["NonExistent"]
```

The value returned is `''`.  How can I change this so that when a key is not found, `"unknown"` is returned instead of the empty string?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The argument to defaultdict is a function (or rather, a callable object) that returns the default value.  So you can pass in a lambda that returns your desired default.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: 'My default')
>>> d['junk']
'My default'
```

Edited to explain lambda:

lambda is just a shorthand for defining a function without giving it a name.  You could do the same with an explicit def:

```
>>> def myDefault():
...     return 'My default'
>>>> d = defaultdict(myDefault)
>>> d['junk']
'My default'
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda) for more info.