# Create a defaultdict with a default of zero (0)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923334/setting-the-default-string-value-of-pythons-collections-defaultdict) I'd like to create a `collections.defaultdict` with a default value of zero for counting elements of a list of tuples:

```
tuples = [('foo', 5), ('foo', 5), ('bar', -5), ('bar', -2)]
totals = defaultdict(0)
for t in tuples:
    totals[t[0]] += t[1]
```

But `defaultdict(0)` says:

```
TypeError: first argument must be callable
```

How am I supposed to create a "callable" zero?

Comment: Also, note that as well as being covered by numerous other questions here, the `defaultdict(int)` example is *given in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)*, so I'm really not sure this is adding value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It being mentioned in the docs is a more powerful argument  for closing than the duplicate question you linked to which, although a superset of this, doesn't quite have the Googleability. I have a tendency to make these Q&A style questions whenever the docstring is opaque and a quick Google doesn't instantly bring joy!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The docstring for `collections.defaultdict` is pretty confusing at first read:

> defaultdict(default_factory[, ...]) --> dict with default factory
>
> The default factory is called without arguments to produce a new value
>   when a key is not present, in **getitem** only. A defaultdict compares
>   equal to a dict with the same items. All remaining arguments are
>   treated the same as if they were passed to the dict constructor,
>   including keyword arguments.

All this is trying to say is that the default "value" has to be a function, and that that function will be called without arguments whenever it's needed (i.e. whenever a normal `dict` would raise a `KeyError`.) The docstring refers to this function as `default_factory`.

The bit with `[, ...]` says that you can optionally pass in an object (or keywords) to use as the `defaultdict`'s initial dictionary. Thus:

```
In [26]: x = defaultdict(lambda: 0, a=1, b=2)

In [28]: dict(x)
Out[28]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

In [29]: x['c'] # This would normally raise a `KeyError`
Out[29]: 0

In [30]: dict(x) # But here it just adds a new key!
Out[30]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0}
```

Any function which returns zero when called with no arguments can be used:

```
In [31]: int()
Out[31]: 0
```

Thus, as per [the counting example from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) you could create a `defaultdict` with a default value of zero with:

```
defaultdict(int)
```